# my ajax is not working in simple javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

my problem is that when click the insert link: 
it returns the value easily without ajax function but soon is put my ajax function here it says insertIt is not defined.

here is my javascript function:

```
<?php require_once('include/classes/Author.php'); ?>
<script language="javascript">
function insertIt(pID, pName)
{
    var obj    = opener.document.form1.<?php echo $_GET['objName']; ?>;
    var found = 0;

    i = 0;

    while ((i < obj.length) && (found == 0)) 
    {
        if (obj[ i ].value == pID) {
            found = 1;
        }
        else 
            i++;
    }

    if (found == 0) {
        obj.length++;
        obj[ obj.length-1 ].value = pID;
        obj[ obj.length-1 ].text  = unescape(pName);
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         // i dont need this...
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("get","<?php print WEB_URL; ?>admin/selectVals.php?value="+pID+"&addRemove=add",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

here is my html whom i am sending values.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td align="left">1</td>
        <td align="left">Land's End</td>
        <td align="left"><a href='javascript:insertIt("57", "Land s End")'>Insert</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">2</td>
        <td align="left">Roe v. Wade at 40</td>
        <td align="left"><a href='javascript:insertIt("58", "Roe v. Wade at 40")'>Insert</a></td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td align="left">3</td>
        <td align="left">Wagner High and Low</td>
        <td align="left"><a href='javascript:insertIt("59", "Wagner High and Low")'>Insert</a></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: any sharp expert please???? i am stuck dear....

Comment: **Danger**: You are echoing user input directly into the page. This renders you vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Can you alert(xmlhttp.status ) before if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)) to check the status

Comment: @Danger: Sir i want to use this script in admin side please.

Comment: @RaunakKathuria Sir, it always says insertIt is not defined...

Comment: @RaunakKathuria it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: insertIt is not defined

Comment: without ajax piece of code my all is working fine. but soon i insert ajax here it stop working

Comment: Can you remove this line (just to test) and check xmlhttp.open("get","<?php print WEB_URL; ?>admin/selectVals.php?value="+pID+"&addRemove=add",true); may be some of your variables are not properly defined

Comment: which line sir??? can you please explain?

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: i have removed this: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         // i dont need this...
        }
    }

Comment: and run the function onclick event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of href use onclick

```
onclick= 'insertIt("57", "Land s End");return false' href=''
```

Comment: it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: insertIt is not defined

Comment: i have debug it in console

Comment: it refreshes the page and insertIt function also stops working

Comment: its no NOT working as expected previously like i want to insert value in select tag with submitting value to ajax. i dont know why its not working.....

Comment: make sure that both function and html tags are in same page or reference should be added

Comment: i have removed this: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { // i dont need this... } }
and run the function on a onclick event..

Comment: no no its totally fine...  have u tried my updated answer ??? just look at it and check whether it is working or not... i have given yo the code which i have been using in my projects